# Opening a directory automatically after creating with CreateDirectory

Tags: c++, fstream, prompt

I'm not asking how to create a directory , I mean for example I will ask to user if s/he wants to create a directory and a text output in it , using a yes/no prompt. (everything is done thus far and directory with a text document in it has created)

I want the program to show up that directory automatically when the user says yes.

Is there any way to do this? Thanks!

```
        CreateDirectory ("C:\\MYHRA", NULL);

       cout<<"\n\nDo you want to create a text document of this result? [Y]es / [N]o"<<endl;
        cin>>yorn;

        if (yorn=='y' || yorn=='Y')
                    {
                             ofstream myfile;
                             myfile.open ("C:\\MYHRA\\Result.txt");
                             myfile <<n<<"\n";
                             myfile.close();                                                                            

                    }
        if (yorn=='n' || yorn=='N')
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
```

Comment: What does "show directory" mean in this case? Do you want to "start explorer", or something else?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm asking. I want it to start explorer automatically.